# Material Design: Visually grouping views

Tags: android, material-design, grouping

I have a form with a lot of views like this:

Group 1

- 3 x `EditText`

Group 2

- 6 x `EditText`
- `Switch`

Group 3

- `Switch`

**Problem:**
I think the user would be overwhelmed if I just present those `views` one after another. Additionally grouping would make sense because the data in one group belongs together in a way.

**One idea:**
I thought about using tabs but they would require the user to make another swipe/touch to get where they want. Another problem is that making a tab just for one `Switch` (Group 3) does not seem effective.

**My question:** I am searching for a way that is consistent with the `Material Design` guidelines to group `views`. How can I do that?

Comment: What about a listview with dividers between groups?

Comment: listview would not be efficient, because every group has a different layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: [CardView](https://material.google.com/components/cards.html)

To use, add `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'` to your *build.gradle* file.

Use it like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <!-- put views here that should be grouped -->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like an expandable view:
https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view

Or group them into view groups(Like LinearLayout/RelativeLayout etc as per your convenience) and play with visibility of these viewGroups depending on what data user has entered.(Usually through focus change listeners  on edit text and state change listener on switch). You can use the following Material Design animation to change view visibility:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html

Comment: i don't want to hide anything if possible.

Comment: Then you can go ahead with view pager, ie tabbed views, and when user has filled in all details in first tab, you can manually change the tab by java code.